# How to use sample as an instrument?

Tags: vst, sample, fl-studio

I'd like to use a recorded sample as a virtual instrument.
Mostly I'm using FL Studio, but maybe there is a way which is DAW independent (maybe a VST plugin or something).

For FL Studio specific: If you create a sample channel you can just use it within the piano roll, but the problem is that the time changes with the pitch and so it's not really appropriate to use it as a instrument, or at least not appropriate for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single sample, you're only going to see the same problem with the time change repeated in other samplers. Even with some clever warping in PT or Ableton Live, there is still only so far you can stretch the sample before it becomes unusable (especially when you're pitching it up, but retaining the speed).

The ideal solution is to get more samples recorded of every note and map them to your sampler, but I appreciate this might not be possible.

Have you considered looking for a commercial VST sample library of this particular instrument?

What is the instrument in question? Myself or the guys on here may well know of one, or even have a larger collection of samples available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't think a sample library will cover my needs as I want to use voice samples and stuff alike.

Answer (score 0):

This might not get you the results you're looking for, but if you find a good loop point in the source sample, i.e. one that produces as little audible modulation as possible, you can get the tone to at least play for as long as you want.

Put a nice ASDR envelope over it and you might have something beautiful, if not interesting.